# Unimporting in Scala

Tags: scala, import

I heard recently some advice to *"unimport an implicit conversion from Predef"* - I presume that this means it is possible to `unimport` unwanted classes too:

```
import java.awt._
unimport java.awt.List
```

But this is not the syntax of an "unimport" (i.e. there is no such `unimport` keyword). What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the import alias feature but rename the "unwanted class" to "_".  Since "_" can not be accessed in Scala code as a classname, it hides the renamed class from unqualified access.

```
import java.awt.{List => _, _}
```

Comment: Hmmm - this seems like a clumsy hack `:-(`

Comment: No, it's not a hack, it's just overload on meanings of "_". If used alone in an import clause, it means everything. If used on the right side of an import rename, it means do not import.

Comment: Weird, but hey, that's Scala!