# Scala Predef unimport

Tags: scala, import, predef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to unimport String “+” operator in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664274/how-to-unimport-string-operator-in-scala)

So things from Predef get automatically imported into scala programs. But how can I disable- unimport certain or all imported functions from Predef? As an example if I don't like the '+' operator on String how to disable this functionality?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668328/unimporting-in-scala.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate but I would still like to know how to *unimport* arbitrary import.

Comment: The supposed "exact duplicate" question doesn't answer the question as well as @retronym's answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the linked answer, the method `String#+(other: Any)` is added to the String class with compiler magic, rather than with an implicit conversion. As such, it isn't related to the automatic import of `Predef._`.

The same applies to `Int#+(x: String)`, and corresponding method on the other value types.

However, there is another String concatenation method that *is* added by an implicit conversion in `Predef`. `x + "2"` is treated as `Predef.any2stringAdd(x).+("2")`. By explicitly importing `Predef` on the first line of your file, you can rename unwanted members to `_`, disabling them.

```
import Predef.{any2stringadd => _, _}

object Test {    
  object A
  A + "20" // error: value + is not a member of object Test.A
}
```

I don't think that this works in Scala Scripts or in the REPL. There is also an unsupported option, `-Yno-predef`, to turn of the automatic import globally.

Related: [SI-1931](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1931)

Comment: Thanks! So another use case for te underscore.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 2.10: `import Predef.{boolean2Boolean => _}` -> `[ERROR] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous: both method Boolean2boolean in object Predef of type (x: Boolean)Boolean and method safeBoolean2boolean are possible conversion functions from Boolean to Boolean`

Comment: Predef unimporting has to be done in a file (not in the REPL) and in the very first import.

Comment: SI-1931 lands in 2.11.8, apparently, so it will work in REPL.

Comment: It actually does work in the REPL in `2.11` and `2.12`.